# Does hierarchical partitioning works in AWS Athena/S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am new to AWS and trying to use S3 and Athena for a use case.

I want the data saved as json files in S3 to be queried from Athena. To reduce the data scan i have created directory structure like this

```
../customerid/date/*.json (format)

../100/2020-04-29/*.json
../100/2020-04-30/*.json
.
.
../101/2020-04-29/*.json
```

In Athena the table structure has been created according to the data we are expecting and 2 partitions have been created namely customer (customerid) and dt (date).

I want to query all the data for customer '100' and limit my scan to its directory for which i am trying to load the partition as follows

```
alter table <table_name> add
partition (customer=100) location 's3://<location>/100/’

But I get the following error

FAILED: SemanticException partition spec {customer=100} doesn't contain all (2) partition columns
```

Clearly its not loading a single partition when multiple partitions have been created

Giving both partitions in alter table

```
alter table <table_name> add
partition (customer=100, dt=2020-04-22) location 's3://<location>/100/2020-04-22/'

I get this error

missing 'column' at 'partition' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Does this even works? 
If not is there a way to work with hierarchical partitions?

Comment: Usually what we do is create the table with both the partition spec specified and add partition on a need basis,  also you don't need to specify the S3 location on alter table add partiton command, location is only required while you create the table.

Comment: Try to make use a glue crawler and set the other format of files in your buckets as exclude paths. The crawler will automatically detect your partitions and update the schemas for each partition.

Comment: Could you share the table creation sql as well ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the S3 hierarchial structure that you have given. it should be

```
../customer=100/dt=2020-04-29/*.json
```

instead of

```
../100/2020-04-29/*.json
```

If you have data in S3 stored in the correct prefix structure as mentioned, then you could add partitions with simple msck repair `msck repair table <table_name>` command.

Hope this clarifies

Comment: Nimin, Thanks for your comment but i tried exactly this "the hive format" it still didn't load the JSON.
Its loading if the directory structure is like this ../customer=100/*.json

Comment: did you mean you still cannot see date partitions ? If that is the case could you share the create table ddl ?

Comment: Yes i meant that, but after your comment i rechecked my command there was a typo in the table name. :). It works now thanks.
Only thing is msck repair table <table_name> will load all the partitions which i wanted to avoid thats why used non hive format with alter command. 
Is there a way to load only 1 or few partitions with msck and hive format?

Answer (score 2):

I figured the mistake i was making so wanted to share in case anyone finds themselves in the same situation.

For data not partitioned in hive format (Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) for hive and non-hive format)

Taking the example above, following is the alter command that works

```
alter table <table_name> add
partition (customer=100, dt=date '2020-04-22') location 's3://<location>/100/2020-04-22/'
```

Notice the change in the syntax of "dt" partition. As my partition datatype was set to "date" type and not using it while loading the partition was giving the error.

although not giving the data type also works we just need to give single quotes that defaults the partition type to string/varchar

```
alter table <table_name> add
partition (customer=100, dt='2020-04-22') location 's3://<location>/100/2020-04-22/'
```

I prefer giving the date data type while adding as that is how i configured my partition.

Hope this helps.